# Parallelize for-loop in python

Tags: python, loops, parallel-processing, biopython

I have a simple set of code that runs Clustal Omega (a protein multiple sequence alignment program) from Python:

```
from Bio.Align.Applications import ClustalOmegaCommandline

segments = range(1, 9)
segments.reverse()

for segment in segments:
    in_file = '1.0 - Split FASTA Files/Segment %d.fasta' % segment
    out_file = '1.1 - Aligned FASTA Files/Segment %d Aligned.fasta' % segment
    distmat = '1.1 - Distmats/Segment %d Distmat.fasta' % segment

    cline = ClustalOmegaCommandline(infile=in_file, 
                                    outfile=out_file, 
                                    distmat_out=distmat, 
                                    distmat_full=True, 
                                    verbose=True,
                                    force=True)
    print cline
    cline()
```

I've done some informal tests at timing how long my multiple sequence alignments (MSAs) take. On average, each one takes 4 hours. To run all 8 one after another took me 32 hours in total. Therefore, that was my original intent in running it as a `for` loop - that I could let it run and not worry about it.

However, I did yet another informal test - I took the output from the printed cline, and copied-and-pasted it into 8 separate terminal windows spread across two computers, and ran the MSAs that way. On average, each one took about 8 hours or so... but because they were all running at the same time, it took me only 8 hours to get the results.

In some ways, I've discovered parallel processing! :D

But I'm now faced with the dilemma of how to get it running in Python. I've tried looking at the following SO posts, but I still cannot seem to wrap my head around how the multiprocessing module works.

List of posts:

- [How do I parallelize a simple Python loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786102/how-do-i-parallelize-a-simple-python-loop)
- [Perform a for-loop in parallel in Python 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631457/perform-a-for-loop-in-parallel-in-python-3-2)
- [Parallel loop in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190713/parallel-loop-in-python)
- [how to parallelize big for loops in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18519420/how-to-parallelize-big-for-loops-in-python)

Would anybody be kind enough to share how they would parallelize this loop? Many loops I do look similar to this loop, in which I perform some action on a file and write to another file, without ever needing to aggregate the results in memory. The specific difference I am facing is the need to do file I/O, rather than aggregate results from parallel runs of the loop.

Comment: Since the other posts already state multiple ways to achieve parallelization of a `for` loop, is there something *specific* that troubles you?

Comment: None of the examples deal with file I/O, but instead deal with aggregating the results from parallel runs. At least, that's what I thought when I was reading through the posts. Please pardon my ignorance, I still consider myself a newbie to many computing concepts and to Python.

Comment: If file I/O is what concerns you, please be *explicit* about that in the question. As it currently stands it is an exact duplicate of the questions you linked. However, AFAIK, file I/O isn't anything special. You'll just have to use some locks between processes to avoid meaningless output to the files and you are done.

Comment: @Bakuriu, I have done so in the post from the beginning. Please read the bottom paragraph.

Comment: @ericmjl No it's not clear that the *sole* purpose of your question is how to handle parallel I/O. As it is written it looks like a casual remark on an irrelevant detail of your code. If your question is "How can I handle parallel output to a file?" then *write it*, don't just write "how can I parallelize this loop?" and, in a random place, put "the code happens to contain file I/O".

Comment: @Bakuriu, I took your recommendation and edited in that point as the last statement. On an different note, however, based solely on reading your comment, it took a while to digest what you were saying, as I felt you were coming off as arrogant and pushy, which defeats the need to be welcoming towards newbies and newcomers on SO. I hope we can exchange our ideas respectfully, and that you may read my comment that way too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly the [Joblib library](http://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html) is what you are looking for.

Let me give you an example of its use:

```
import time
from joblib import Parallel, delayed


def long_function():
    time.sleep(1)


REPETITIONS = 4
Parallel(n_jobs=REPETITIONS)(
    delayed(long_function)() for _ in range(REPETITIONS))
```

This code runs in 1 second, instead of 4 seconds.

Adapting your code looks like this (sorry, I can't test if this is correct):

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

from Bio.Align.Applications import ClustalOmegaCommandline


def run(segment):
    in_file = '1.0 - Split FASTA Files/Segment %d.fasta' % segment
    out_file = '1.1 - Aligned FASTA Files/Segment %d Aligned.fasta' % segment
    distmat = '1.1 - Distmats/Segment %d Distmat.fasta' % segment
    cline = ClustalOmegaCommandline(infile=in_file,
                                    outfile=out_file,
                                    distmat_out=distmat,
                                    distmat_full=True,
                                    verbose=True,
                                    force=True)
    print cline
    cline()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    segments = range(1, 9)
    segments.reverse()

    Parallel(n_jobs=len(segments)(
        delayed(run)(segment) for segment in segments)
```

Comment: thank you for this helpful post! May I ask, assuming this is run from the IPython notebook, would I take the section under `if __name__ == '__main__':`, put that in one cell, and run that cell?

Comment: Yes, if the rest of the code is included in a previous cell that has been evaluated, then you can run it as you have described.

Comment: This does not work in my version of python..It says there is no such module.

Comment: @robbieboy74: have you installed the Joblib library? It is not a standard module

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `for segment in segments`, write `def f(segment)` and then use `multiprocessing.Pool().map(f, segments)`

Figuring out how to put this in context is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I think using `imap` instead of `map` might be appropriate here as the runtimes are so long.